# Select only birthday in Facebook graph API 2.1

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, events, calendar

I would like to select only the birthday date in the Facebook graph api, and not the ID user. 
I've written : me?fields=birthday
And the NSLog gives me : `"  "birthday": "05/24/1993", 
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxx""`
I would like only "05/24/1993 for getting birthday date and saves that in Parse.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what fields you add to the `fields` parameter, the `id` for the user will always be returned at the minimum. You cannot filter it out.

Comment: Oops, I have repost, but I wanted to comment…